Why static friction can act on centre of mass acceleration but similar force can not
I’ve got two scenarios involving a wheel on a rough horizontal surface.
Scenario 1.
A force is applied horizontally through the wheels centre of mass.
My understanding is that this force minus the force of static friction gives the net force on the centre of mass of the wheel, whilst static friction also causes the wheel to rotate when it’s rolling without slipping.
Scenario 2.
The wheel is now placed on a treadmill that is the same material as the surface in scenario 1. The treadmill applies force at the wheels contact point with the treadmill and in the opposite direction to the force through the centre of mass as in scenario 1.
My confusion is that I’ve heard it said that “if the wheel is free to spin the force from the treadmill will only rotate the wheel”. However in scenario 1 the static friction acted in the same location and same direction as this force from the treadmill but not only did it rotate the wheel it also acted on the wheels centre of mass.
So I’m wondering does the force from treadmill not act on the wheels centre of mass like static friction did.

"So I’m wondering does the force from treadmill not act on the wheels centre of mass" It does; the frictional force can be replaced by a force on the center of mass plus a moment around the center of mass. Perhaps you could clarify your question to expand on who is saying differently and why.

Thanks for the response. This began with a question that was posted on TikTok. The question was “could a 747 take off on a treadmill runway when the treadmill is powered such that at all times the treadmill moves with a speed equal to the speed of the planes wheels”

There’s of course many other details and assumptions needed to give a complete answer to that question (they weren’t  given on TikTok) but many suggested that because the wheels are free to spin the planes centre of mass wouldn’t move if the treadmill was ran underneath it, only the planes wheels would be span by the treadmill. This is what got me thinking about how friction works in various rolling scenarios and here we are haha.

And that the plane could take off normally when the thrust from the engines are applied because the force from the treadmill is not opposing this thrust on the planes centre of mass. I agree with that but i then I had the issue that I’ve posted here in the question. I can’t see how the treadmill could only spin the wheels yet static friction can spin the wheels and effect the COM in various rolling scenarios such as a ball rolling down an incline plane.

It's not really possible to answer a question with an incorrect premise. Any force applied by a treadmill on a wheel does act on the wheel's center of mass, so there's no answer to why it "does...not act". Now, this force might be negligible compared to a plane's thrust, but it's still present.

Thanks for the clarification, how do we determine the magnitude of the force that is seen on the centre of mass when a a force is applied tangential to a uniform disc for example

The magnitude is the same.

In the first scenario, the resultant force is $F_R = F_{CM}-F_{fr}$. In the second one, it is: $F_R = -F_{fr}$ (supposing the same force of static friction). The acceleration of the centre of mass is $$a_{CM}=\frac{F_R}{m_w}$$.
So, in both cases the centre of mass accelerates and the wheel rotates (due to the torque with respect to the CM). But as the resultant force is different, that acceleration is also different.
What is equal is the angular acceleration of the wheel because the torque is the same by hypothesis.
